# How do I reduce the quality of an image in byte format on Android?

Tags: android, image, upload, compression

Using resources from StackOverflow and other helpful websites, I was successful in creating an application that can upload an image taken by the camera application on an Android phone.  The only trouble is, the phone I have right now takes very high-quality pictures, resulting in a long wait-time for uploads.

I read about converting images from jpeg to a lower rate (smaller size or just web-friendly sizes), but the code I am using right now saves the captured image as a byte (see code below).  Is there any way to reduce the quality of the image in the form that it is in, or do I need to find a way to convert it back to jpeg, reduce the image quality, and then place it back in byte form?

Here is the code snippet I'm working with:

```
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {

        if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            try {

                // Get resource path from intent callee
                Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

                // Query gallery for camera picture via
                // Android ContentResolver interface
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
                // Get binary bytes for encode
                byte[] data = getBytesFromFile(is);

                // base 64 encode for text transmission (HTTP)
                int flags = 1;
                byte[] encoded_data = Base64.encode(data, flags);
                // byte[] encoded_data = Base64.encodeBase64(data);
                String image_str = new String(encoded_data); // convert to
                                                                // string

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",
                        image_str));

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://xxxxx.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this,
                        "Response " + the_string_response,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Error in http connection "
                        + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For web apps, you definitely don't need the 5+ MP images that cameras produce; image resolution is the primary factor in image size, so I'd suggest you use the BitmapFactory class to produce a downsampled bitmap.

Particularly, look at BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(), and pass it a BitmapFactory.Options parameter indicating you want a downsampled bitmap.

```
// your bitmap data
byte[] rawBytes = .......... ;

// downsample factor
options.inSampleSize = 4;  // downsample factor (16 pixels -> 1 pixel)

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.length, options);
```

For more info, take a look at the Android Training lesson on displaying bitmaps efficiently and the reference for BitmapFactory:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Comment: For the inSampleSize, will this continue to downsize the sample by a factor of 4 even when the camera resolution is very small?

Comment: Ideally, you should calculate the downsample factor according to your needs -- you can first check the image's dimensions by decoding only the boundaries (that's an option in the options parameter) and then you can calculate what downsample factor you need, then decode it for real using that factor. Take a look at the Displaying Bitmaps lesson (first link), it has really useful example code for exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

To tell the decoder to subsample the image, loading a smaller version into memory, set inSampleSize to true in your BitmapFactory.Options object. For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384. Loading this into memory uses 0.75MB rather than 12MB for the full image (assuming a bitmap configuration of ARGB_8888). see this

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

```
public   Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
  String pathName) {
int reqWidth,reqHeight;
reqWidth =Utils.getScreenWidth();
reqWidth = (reqWidth/5)*2;
reqHeight = reqWidth;
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
//  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
}

   public   int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
  int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
  if (width > height) {
    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
  } else {
    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
  }
}
return inSampleSize;
 }
```