# Android : Skipped 417 Frames . Message from Choreographer when trying to load image from database

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am retrieving data from a database using a service. In the DB, I have stored the image in the form of bytes, because of the response from the request is huge. Anyways, when i try getting the values, i get an error saying that 417 frames skipped, the application is doing too much work. I running the whole request on the AsyncTask, so it is getting performed in the back ground. I do not know why the error is occuring.

The snippet is as follows:-

```
    private class NetworkCall  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, CharSequence>{

    @Override
    protected CharSequence doInBackground(Void... params) {
        CharSequence seqResult = null;

        try{

            //http post request

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/HookService/SvcFiles/Hook.svc/GetAllUsers");
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            int p_iRadius = 20;

            JSONStringer postParameters = new JSONStringer()
            .object()
                .key("p_iRadius").value(p_iRadius)
            .endObject();

            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(postParameters.toString()));   

            //get the response
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            // stream reader object
            Reader resultReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
            //create a buffer to fill if from reader
            char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity().getContentLength()];
            //fill the buffer by the help of reader
            resultReader.read(buffer);
            //close the reader streams
            resultReader.close();
            seqResult = java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Web Service Error", "Web Service error", e);
        }

        return seqResult;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(CharSequence Result){      
            JSONArray resultArray = null;

            try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Result.toString());
            resultArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ReturnModel");
                //resultArray = new JSONArray(Result.toString());
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Json error", "Json error", e);
            }

            GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
            DateDeserializer ds = new DateDeserializer();
            gsonb.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, ds);
            Gson gson = gsonb.create();
            Type datasetListType = new TypeToken<Collection<MapPushPinData>>() {}.getType();

            try{
            mapUserList = gson.fromJson(resultArray.toString(), datasetListType);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Serialization Error", "Error", e);
            }

            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }
}
```

Basically I obtain the credentials to plot the marker on map with a small image and name. when the request is made, the frames are skipped because of which the markers are not plotted.

Also I am running this on the emulator, and I cannot test it on the device because it is not possible for my device to be included on the same network.

Comment: are you running this on a real phone or the emulator

Comment: @Rarw emulator. presently i cannot run it on my phone as my phone is not a part of the network.

Comment: Emulator is notoriously slow for this kind of stuff. Try running it on a real phone and see if the issue persists. My other suggestion is to downsample the image as you load it from the db.

Comment: @Rarw yes i wish i could do it. but the place where i am trying to get this done is pretty restrictive. so i would not be able to test it on the phone.

Comment: Try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809445/how-do-i-reduce-the-quality-of-an-image-in-byte-format-on-android) and downsample the image as loading

Comment: @Rarw good idea will try it.

Comment: You should also move all non-UI code (i.e. everything but the `setupMapIfNeeded()` part) into the `doInBackground()` method.